# Galois They $Aut(K/F) \leq [K:F] < \infty$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, galois-theory, definition, automorphism-group

This is corollary 10, page 585 in Dummit&Foote. It is followed immediately after proving that

> **Theorem 9**: If $G = \{1,\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_n\} \leq Aut(K)$ with fixed field $F$ then
>
> $$[K:F] = n = |G|$$
>
> **Corollary 10:** Let $K/F$ be any finite extension. Then $$|Aut(K/F)| \leq [K:F]$$
> with equality $\iff F$ is fixed field of $Aut(K/F).$

Here is the proof for reference (it's not important)

> Let $F_1$ be fixed field of $Aut(K/F)$ so that $F \subset F_1 \subset K.$ Then $[K:F_1] = | Aut(K/F)|.$ Hence $[K:F] = |Aut(K/F)|[F_1:F] \geq |Aut(K/F)|.$

I have some questions about the notation mainly and what we are proving

**Q1:** I thought the notation $Aut(K/F)$ means exactly automorphisms with fixed field $F$ by definition. This is the very first thing introduced in the chapter.

**Q2:** So shouldn't the statement then be reworded to

$$|Aut(K/F_1) \leq [K: F]$$ with equality $\iff F = F_1.$

**Q3:** This refinement seems to be consistent with **corollary 11** that follows which briefly states if $G$ is a finite subgroup of $|Aut(K/F_*)$ with fixed field $F_*$, then the "missing" automorphisms fixing $F_*$ are still in $G$, in other words $G = Aut(K/F_*)$ is the whole group. Do I have this right?

Comment: Q1. $\text{Aut}(K/F)$ is the set of automorphisms $\sigma$ of $K$ with the property that $\sigma(a)=a$ for all $a\in F$. Q2. The statement needn't be reworded. Q3. I don't understand this.

Comment: Q1: Right so $F$ is the fixed field of $Aut(K/F)$, so what are we trying prove? Q3 isn't really a true question. I am just asking if I got the idea of the statement right. The official statement is $G$ is a finite subgroup of $Aut(K)$ and $F$ the fixed field, then  $\forall \sigma \in Aut(K)$, $\sigma \in G$, i.e. $G = Aut(K/F).$

Comment: Q1: No, $F$ needn’t be the fixed field of $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$, it might just be a subfield of the fixed field. The fact that the fixed field might be larger is kind of what the Corollary is getting at.

Comment: @EikeSchulte, I am not understanding the subtlety here. As in the statement, let $F \subset F_1$ and $F_1$ be the fixed field, hence $\sigma(f_1) = f_1$ fixes $F_1$. So $F$ being a subset of $F_1$ surely also gets all of its elements fixed by $\sigma$ right?

Answer (score 2):

By $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ we mean the group of all automorphisms $\sigma$ of $K$ that fix $F$ (pointwise), i.e. $\sigma(x) = x$ for all $x \in F$. This is *not* the same as saying that $F$ is the fixed field of every automorphism in $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ because it is okay if these automorphisms fix additional elements of $K$ that are not in $F$. For example, the identity morphism is always an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ and it fixes every element of $K$ regardless of whether it is in $F$ or not. So the fixed field of an element $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ contains $F$ but it might be bigger.

Now the theorems in your question do not talk about the fixed fields of individual elements of $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ but about the fixed field of the group $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ as a whole. By that we mean the subfield of $K$ consisting of those elements that are fixed by every automorphism in $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$. In other words, it is the intersection of the fixed fields of the individual automorphims. This is again a field, it certainly contains $F$ and we would like it to be exactly $F$. But alas, this last part still need not be true: For example, for the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ the automorphism group consists only of the identity. Hence the fixed field of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q})$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and not $\mathbb{Q}$.

Quite soon you should learn that what we want is true for certain field extensions $K/F$ called *Galois extensions* and these are therefore the main interest of Galois theory.